# How to setup a fixed port for a local debug environment in Azure Emulator

Tags: azure

I have some smoke and UI tests that I can run when my web and worker roles are deployed to azure but I would like to do the same on my local computer when I am developping. The problem is that I don't know how to force the ip:port of the the web role deployed . Any idea ?

Answer (score 6):

Windows Azure Compute Emulator picks up the IP addresses from `DevFC.exe.config` file in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\devfabric` folder. The setting names for IP address range are `VipPoolStartIPAddress` and `VipPoolEndIPAddress`. When a service starts in the emulator, the emulator service picks up 1st available IP address from this range. If you're working with just one cloud service, you can set the value in both of these settings as the same IP address and your cloud service will pick up that IP address only.

As far as port is concerned, by default it runs the cloud service on port 80 (and then dynamically switches it to port 81 to avoid port conflict). You could specify another port in your cloud service `csdef` file under `Enpoints` section. For example, in our case we always wanted the service to run on port 1001 and we have this setting:

```
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="1001" />
</Endpoints>
```

Two things to remember:

- Once you change the setting in DevFC.exe.config, you will need to restart compute emulator for this setting to take effect.
- These settings are reset when you install newer version of SDK so you would need to change the settings in DevFC.exe.config file after you install a newer version of SDK.

Comment: Very instructive and useful. Will try to dig a little bit more as it not completely solve my issue regarding running ui web test on my emulated environment but give me hints on where to start.

Comment: Please share the solution you come up with. We may decide to go with that approach ourselves as well.

Comment: @GauravMantri hi, can I set different port for local and cloud?

Comment: @JerryBian Would you mind posting it as a separate question? Thanks.

Comment: @GauravMantri sure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234807/how-to-set-separate-port-for-local-and-cloud-in-azure

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, and changing the port didn't fix it.  It turned out that another process was causing the issue.  Another user had a disconnected session on the machine that I was using, and he had a process running that was called "csmonitor.exe", with the description "Windows Azure Simulation Monitor".  I killed that process, and then I was able to debug.