# How to set separate port for local and cloud in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

For development purpose, we want to specify the port of EndPoint only for local, and the real used port for cloud deployment, any way to get this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the endpoints are defined in `csdef` file which goes into the package, one possible solution would be to create two separate cloud projects - one for local and other for cloud and define ports which needs to be opened according to the environment. In fact, this is what we did in one of our projects.

[image]

Other idea would be to apply XDT transformation to your csdef file. Please see this blog post for more details: [`http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/apply-xdt-transforms-to-your-servicedefinition-csdef-file/`](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/apply-xdt-transforms-to-your-servicedefinition-csdef-file/)

Comment: I prefer the first approach, since it's very simple and clean. The second one is something like hacked, maybe waiting for official support this feature is better.

Comment: In the first approach, only thing one needs to be careful about is configuration settings in 'cscfg' file as you would now need to define the settings in both projects.